# How to create a guided tour in Rails with gem 'intros-rails'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, intro.js

Been working on this for a few days, I'm trying to use gem "introjs-rails" to create a guided tour in rails.  https://github.com/heelhook/intro.js-rails.  A few differences between whats below and what the guide asks for are the guide wants '//= require introjs' to be put in application.js, but I get a Javascript error of 'introJs().start(); is undefined variable' so I put '//= require introjs' in the 'Intro.js' file instead and that seems to fix it.  But when I start up the page, I'm still not getting a pop up message to appear.

Application.html.erb

```
<head>
  <title>Workspace</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'introjs', 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'intro', 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Application.scss

```
/*
 *= require introjs
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
*/
```

Index.html.erb

```
<h1 data-step="1" data-intro="This is a tooltip!">This is a Tool Tip!</h1>
```

Intro.js

```
//= require introjs
introJs().start();
```

Introjs.css

```
 *= require introjs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

Index.html.erb:

```
<a class='introduction-farm' href='#' data-intro='Hello step one!'></a>
```

Intro.js:

```
introJs(".introduction-farm").start();
```

> As you suggested in the comment, loading the script too earlier was the source of the issue for you : `setTimeout(function() { introJs().start(); }, 3000);`

For your CSS issue, most likely `jQuery` was not referenced, in which case you need to include it before `IntroJS`, `bootstrap`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmmm no luck unfortunately.

Comment: Can you show us the console log when starting the app!

Comment: Oh that's interesting.  It says "There is no class with the given selector".  I checked the code again and the classes are the same in intro.js and index.html.erb.  And when I click on the Global error in the console it points to "introJs(".introduction-farm").start();"

Comment: wait what do you mean by "in intro.js", you know that the changes are not to be done inside `intro.js`? Why don't you try the `HelloWorld` example I suggested (if any changes were done to `intro.js` remove them or use the original file)

Comment: I was referring to the first suggestion you made, let me work on your second one.

Comment: I figured out part of it.  The JS was loading too early which is why it couldn't find a class.  So for intro.js I put  `setTimeout(function() { introJs().start(); }, 3000);`.  It looks like the CSS isn't being applied though, because here is a screenshot of what I'm getting.  https://imgur.com/a/plBpZFR Excited some progress was made though.  And the text 'one two' is just what I put for some example text.

Comment: Great to hear that, I updated my answer accordingly, I hope you accept the answer ;)

Comment: Haha! sure thing.  I appreciate you helping me work through it.  Do you think you could take one last look to see if you can think why the CSS isn't loading though?

Comment: Haha sure thing, can you screenshot the css loading via `Inspect>Network>CSS` and `console log`

Comment: I think your instruction are for Chrome?  I'm on Safari, but I can go into Page Resources which show me the CSS of the page.  Interestingly when I inspect the 'pop up message' (the elements I uploaded to imgur) it gives me the following.  https://imgur.com/a/yMIUK0U.  So the elements do have introjs css classes applied to them, but it just looks all plain on the view.

Comment: I see now,You should make sure your `jquery` link placed first then write  ... javascript link, `bootstrap` ...